# Confluent.Kafka.KafkaException: Broker: Specified group generation id is not valid

Tags: apache-kafka

#### Environment

- 3-node Kafka Cluster

  - Amazon MSK
  - v2.3
- 1 topic

  - 6 partitions
- 1 consumer group with 2 consumers

  - Running in Kubernetes
  - Confluent .NET SDK 1.2.2
  - Except for `bootstrap.servers` and `group.id`, all of the default settings.

#### Problem

First, one of my consumers encounters the following exception.

```
Confluent.Kafka.KafkaException: Broker: Specified group generation id is not valid
   at Confluent.Kafka.Impl.SafeKafkaHandle.Commit(IEnumerable`1 offsets)
   at Confluent.Kafka.Consumer`2.Commit(IEnumerable`1 offsets)
```

The exception is trapped and the consumer is supposed to retry, but instead the app sits idle.  The container is still up and running, but not consuming any more messages.

What's weirder is that the broker never reassigns that consumer's partitions so the consumer lag on those partitions begins to grow.  It seems like the consumer is both alive (since the broker is not reassigning its partitions) and dead (since it cannot commit its offset or consume more messages).  If we intervene and manually restart the consumers then the partitions are reassigned and the situation goes back to normal.

I'm not entirely sure what to make of the exception above.  Google doesn't offer much.  The most relevant lead I have is [this issue in GitHub](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/issues/368), which involves a broker restarting.  To my knowledge, that is not happening in my situation.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into a similar situation.

Comment: I got the same error now. Do you have a solution for it ?

Answer (score -2):

at least I have found a solution for me.
In my code I did a **manual commit** and set `EnableAutoCommit = false`.

Somehow it was possible that for an offset a commit was executed twice. I removed the manual commits on the consumer and set `EnableAutoCommit = true`.

After that it worked.

Comment: Auto commits are fundamentally at odds with producing transactionally.